# QScrollArea not respecting contentMargins setting

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qscrollarea

[QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qscrollarea.html), for some reason, is ignoring the `contentMargins` setting when I set [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qgraphicsview.html) as its widget. Looking at the snippet below, can someone please tell if I'm doing something wrong or it could be a bug in the SDK?

Snippet 1 (works perfect):

```
QWidget *appWindow = new QWidget;

QScrollArea *sa = new QScrollArea(appWindow);
sa->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
sa->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
sa->setContentMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);

QWidget *widgetToScroll = new QWidget(sa);
widgetToScroll->resize(5000, 5000);
sa->setWidget(widgetToScroll);

QVBoxLayout *appWindowLayout = new QVBoxLayout(appWindow);
appWindowLayout->addWidget(sa);
appWindow->setLayout(appWindowLayout);

appWindow->show();
```

Snippet 2 (It's like [setContentMargins()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#setContentsMargins) call is ignored completely):

```
QWidget *appWindow = new QWidget;

QScrollArea *sa = new QScrollArea(appWindow);
sa->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
sa->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
sa->setContentMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);

QGraphicsView *widgetToScroll = new QGraphicsView(new QGraphicsScene(sa), sa);
widgetToScroll->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
widgetToScroll->resize(5000, 5000);
sa->setWidget(widgetToScroll);

QVBoxLayout *appWindowLayout = new QVBoxLayout(appWindow);
appWindowLayout->addWidget(sa);
appWindow->setLayout(appWindowLayout);

appWindow->show();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing the structure of how to nest a QGraphicsView and a QGraphicsScene.  (Maybe it was just a typo?)

```
    QGraphicsView *widgetToScroll = new QGraphicsView(new QGraphicsScene(sa), sa);
```

should be changed to

```
    QGraphicsView *widgetToScroll = new QGraphicsView(new QGraphicsScene(), sa);
```

or

```
    QGraphicsView *widgetToScroll = new QGraphicsView();
    sa->setWidget(widgetToScroll);
```

When you add a QWidget to a layout, you change the widget's parent.  When you set a widget (or QGraphicsView) to a QScrollArea, you change that widget's parent. See [Object Trees & Ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) for more information. So if you wanted to set up your QGraphicsView inside a QScrollArea your code would look like this:

```
    QWidget *appWindow = new QWidget;

    QScrollArea *sa = new QScrollArea(); // No need to specify a parent here if
                                         // you add it to a layout later
    sa->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    sa->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    sa->setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);

    QGraphicsView *widgetToScroll = new QGraphicsView();
    widgetToScroll->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    widgetToScroll->resize(5000, 5000);
    sa->setWidget(widgetToScroll); // This sets the parent for widgetToScroll

    QVBoxLayout *appWindowLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    appWindowLayout->addWidget(sa); // This sets the parent for sa
    appWindow->setLayout(appWindowLayout); // This sets the parent for appWindowLayout

    appWindow->show();
```

As a side note...

When using QGraphicsViews with a QGraphicsScene, instead of setting the margins using a QScrollArea's setContentsMargins, I use the QGraphicsView automatic scrolling and just set the scene rect to have a larger margin that the size of my content like so:

```
    QWidget *appWindow = new QWidget;

    QGraphicsView *widgetToScroll = new QGraphicsView();
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->addRect(0,0, 5000, 5000);

    widgetToScroll->setSceneRect(-50,-50, 5050, 5050);
    widgetToScroll->setScene(scene);

    QVBoxLayout *appWindowLayout = new QVBoxLayout(appWindow);
    appWindowLayout->addWidget(widgetToScroll);

    appWindow->setLayout(appWindowLayout);
    appWindow->show();
```

The QGraphicsView includes quite a bit more than just automatic scrolling when needed.  You can resize everything inside of it and quite a bit more.  It is great for 2D layouts, interactions and animations.  See Qt's Graphics View Framework at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html for more information.

Here is more information that may be useful when using margins and paddings: [The Box Model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model) used by QStyleSheets.

Answer (score 4):

To make the content margins work properly for a QScrollArea widget I subclass it and manually set the viewport margins (which is a protected method in QT 4.7)

```
// Extended class
class QScrollAreaWithMargins : public QScrollArea
{
public:

    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override
    {
        // Define content margins here
        setViewportMargins(5, 0, 0, 0); // <<<<< SET MARGINS HERE
        QScrollArea::resizeEvent(event);
    }
};

// Usage
//...
mEditorScrollArea = new QScrollAreaWithMargins();
//...
```